# button pressed stays true

Tags: python, listener, keyboard-events

My code should press "p" twice, after pressing the letter "u" on the keyboard, . This also works. But when I press "u" twice in quick succession, the code hangs up and the function somehow keeps calling itself, even though I don't press "u" at all. Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import time



def on_press(key):  # The function that's called when a key is pressed
   
    if keyboard.is_pressed('u'): #'u' is pressed 
            
            keyboard.press('p')
            keyboard.release('p')
            time.sleep(0.01)
            keyboard.press('p')
            keyboard.release('p')
            time.sleep(1)
          
    else:
            pass



with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:  # Create an instance of Listener
    listener.join()  # Join the listener thread to the main thread to keep waiting for keys
```

Comment: Is the issue that 'u' still counts as pressed when it presses 'p' because you're still in the handler for 'u' being pressed (i.e. you've already confirmed that 'u' is pressed and nothing has changed yet when you come back into this function)?

Comment: @Kemp yes i think thats the problem...

Comment: You probably want to do something with tracking the state of 'u', so if you set the "u is pressed" flag and then come back into the function and it's still set you don't execute your additional key presses. You'd need to register to listen for releases to reset that flag.

Comment: i solved the problem. I changed "Keyboard.is_pressed('u') == true" with "key == 'u'". Now it works perfectly!

Comment: congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the code under the `keyboard.is_pressed('u')` takes 1.001 seconds to execute (or slightly more) because of the `time.sleep` calls. If you press U twice in less than 1.001 seconds, it is breaking because the function can't finish before you call it again.

Comment: but if I delete " time.sleep(1)", the problem occurs even more frequently (i.e. even if I don't press "u" so quickly in succession)